# Why C + + defines a one-dimensional array of indefinite length, the result made me surprised

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my code

```
char *t = type1[j];
int ln = strlen(t);
char *s = new char[ln];
cout<<"ln  "<<ln<<"   s   "<<strlen(s)<<endl;
```

When I run it:

[image]

Why are the lengths different?

Comment: The contents of memory pointed to by `s` are uninitialized. Examining these contents with `strlen(s)` exhibits undefined behavior. `strlen` doesn't do what you seem to think it does; [read its documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) to find out how it actually works.

Comment: But when I assign to s, its length remains unchanged.

Comment: What do you mean by "its length"?

Comment: It contains the number of elements.

Comment: As I said, `strlen` doesn't compute "the number of elements" that `s` points to.

Comment: haha,thank you very much!When I add s with the ending symbol, perfect!

Answer (score 1):

When you dynamically allocate an array with `new[]`, you get a pointer to an uninitialized block of memory.  You can't call `strlen` on it, as that function expects a pointer to a character array that contains a null-terminated string.  It works by reading each byte in the array until it finds a null byte and returning the count of how many bytes it read before it found a null byte.  And since the array is uninitialized, calling `strlen` does make sense.  In fact, it invokes undefined behavior.

There's no way to look at a dynamically allocated buffer and find out how big that buffer is.  You need to keep track of the size of the buffer separately.  Since you used `new char[ln]` to create the buffer, you know that you have a buffer large enough to hold `ln` variables of type `char`.

Comment: haha,thank you very much!When I add s with the ending symbol, perfect!